# redirect_to another URL after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

After creating a @page on my controller, I'd like to redirect to a path which equals

```
/@page.unique
```

i.e. /24dds3

I've got the 'show' action set up for it:

```
def show
  @page = Page.find_by(unique: params[:id])
end
```

But I can't figure out how to fix the redirect at the end of the create action

Comment: How about `redirect_to "/#{@page.unique}"`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `redirect_to resourcename_path(@object)`

more detailed

```
def create

@object = Model.new(params[:values])

if @object.save

  redirect_to resourcename_path(@object)
else
  render 'new'
end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

so you can do

```
redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @page.unique
```

If you want to omit controllername from URL
you can create try a match route in routes.rb

```
get '/:id', to: 'pages#show', :as => :myurl
```

Comment: so you just want to omit /pages?

Comment: yeah, that's the plan!